# Can swift write a file to a Dropbox folder's URL without using Swifty Dropbox SDK/API?

Tags: swift, dropbox, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

My Swift app needs to write 1KB of string data once a second to a file within my folder on Dropbox, in my Dropbox account.

My app specifies a different filename each second, but the folder URL is constant.

This is a one time app for R&D, not a product, only ever to be used by me.

Comment: Short answer nope

Comment: What platform? Mac, or iOS? (Or Linux, for that matter.)

Comment: @DuncanC he said upload without using the dropbox api. AFAIK he can only download it. macOS he could simply write it directly to the dropbox directory and wait it automatically synchronize it.

Comment: iphone on iOS..

Comment: Thanks, Leo.  Ok, on to Swifty dropbox API...

Comment: Leo, most Mac apps these days are sandboxed, and are only allowed to write the the app's docs/downloads/caches directories, without special permission from the user. Given that it's an R&D app he could bypass that whole mess, but running non-sandboxed apps takes extra steps.

Comment: (But you probably know all that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER IS:   NO.

WORKAROUND IS:   Instead, use:   Swifty DropBox SDK and API